# I have N objects and I want to know which one is the heaviest and lightest

Tags: combinatorics

Say I only want to know the heaviest. If I have a balancing scale, that will require N-1 balancing scale.

If I want to know the lightest.

Same.

What about if I want to know both the heaviest and lightest?

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/lower-bound-for-finding-second-largest-element/ I think of the notes linked from there answers your question as well; if someone looks over them they may post an answer.